# integrate azure DevOps with Github

Tags: github, azure-devops

I use azure devops for daily use to commit and push code, but the code that builds up the dockerfile and ECS it's in github.

Is there a way for every commit that i do in Azure DevOps, that commit to go directly to github!

I did these steps in the pipeline:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 * * * *" # Runs every hour
  displayName: Daily deployment
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  always: true

variables:
- group: GitHubPAT

jobs:
- job: DeployToGitHub
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true

  - script: |
      git config --global user.email "xxx@yyy.com"
      git config --global user.name "enluad"
      git fetch origin develop
      git checkout develop
      git add .
      git remote add github https://${GitHubPAT}@github.com/username/projectname
      git push github HEAD:develop --force

    displayName: 'Push to GitHub'
    env:
      GitHubPAT: $(GitHubPAT)
```

But this pipeline it's giving me this error:

```
From https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyy/_git/monorepo
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      develop    -> origin/develop
Previous HEAD position was ebf78c3 Update pipeline.yml for Azure Pipelines
Switched to a new branch 'develop'
branch 'develop' set up to track 'origin/develop'.
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/projectname/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: UPDATE**:
This actually works out, just I had to give access to my user in GitHub!


Thnx! nvm

Comment: Yes, the git commands in the pipeline can push the commits to Github repo successfully. The cause of the issue is that the Github PAT token has no write permission to the target repo in Github.  If you need to sync every commit from Azure Repo to github repo, you can set the CI trigger in Azure Pipeline. You can refer to my answer for more details.

Comment: Why would you not just standardize on one platform? Choose either GitHub or Azure DevOps for your repository.

Answer (score 0):

> remote: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/projectname/': The requested URL returned error: 403

From the error message, the cause of the issue could be that the Github PAT token has no write permission.

To solve this issue, you need to create a new Github token and  grant the repo write permission to the token.

For example: Navigate to  **Github Settings -> personal access token (classic) -> Generate new token(Classic)**

[image]

Then you can select the repo Read and Write permission to generate the PAT token.

For example:

[image]

You can use the New Github PAT token in your Azure Pipeline to run the git command.

> Is there a way for every commit that i do in Azure DevOps, that commit to go directly to github!

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you can set the [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) for the Pipeline.

For example:

```
trigger:
- main
- releases/*
```

When the trigger branches have new commits, it will automatically trigger the pipeline to sync the commit to Github Repo.